# grep word in text files using perl

Tags: perl, command-line

I have a text file A00010.txt A00011.txt A00012.txt to A00099.txt in myfolder which contains different entries like,

```
umxwtdn8vtnt_n
umxwtdtnt_nn8v
umxwt_ntdn8vtn
u8vtnt_nmxwtdn
utnt_nmxwtdn8v
```

my perl code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

        my $count = 10; 
        for ($count = 10; $count<= 99; $count++) { 
            my $result = `/bin/cat /myfolder/A000$count.txt  | grep "umxwtdn8vtnt_n"`;
            return $result;
        }

     print $result;
```

i trying to get $result value but show empty

Comment: What do you mean you're trying to get the $result value? You want all the matching lines?

Comment: no i just need one value only

Comment: Then I can tell you the answer: the value you are looking for is `umxwtdn8vtnt_n`. Which doesn't make sense.

Comment: print show empty but if i run command on turminal its show output

Comment: Still trying to understand your question, sorry. Are you saying that you want to know if the pattern is at least in one of your files?

Comment: Print is empty because you are exiting the script before the print statement if any is found. Is that what your problem is?

Comment: after get value $result i need to use this value in other function

Answer (score 3):

Is `/myfolder` really in the root directory? (what do you see in `ls /`? Do you see `myfolder`?) It's very rare to add things in the root directory in a Unix system, and I don't think you are messing with `/`.

Also, you are returning `$result` outside a subroutine (`sub { }`), and if that's the case, you should get a Perl runtime error.

If you are copying code fragments, then please note that `$result` is a local variable and it disappears after a subroutine ends.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need to use Perl?

If not:

```
find /myfolder -name "A000??.txt" | xargs grep -n "umxwtdn8vtnt_n"
```

Will find the pattern in your files and tell you at which line...

Would you like to know if the pattern is in one or more of your files? Then:

```
 my $not_found = 1;
 for (my $count = 10; $count<= 99; $count++) { 
    my $result = `grep "umxwtdn8vtnt_n" /myfolder/A000$count.txt`;
    if ($result) {
        print $result;
        $not_found = 0; # error level 0 = no error = found
        last;
    }
 }
 exit $not_found; # error level 1 = error = not found
```

Still trying to understand your need... what about:

```
my $result;
for (my $count = 10; $count<= 99; $count++) { 
   # you should test that A000$count.txt actually exists here
   my $match = `grep "umxwtdn8vtnt_n" /myfolder/A000$count.txt`;
   if ($match == "umxwtdn8vtnt_n") {
        print "found $match in A000${count}.txt";
        $result = $match;
        last; # exit for loop
    }
}
if ($result) {
    # do something with it?
}
```

Comment: how to use $result outside for (my $count = 10; $count<= 99; $count++) { //code }

Comment: i mean 

my one function outside for loop and i need to use $result value in this function

Comment: How can you use it outside the function when you defined in the local scope of loop?

Comment: i test findmypattern function findmypattern(); but not show any result

Comment: Like SHiNKiROU said are you sure your files are in `/myfolder`? The fact that that folder is in the root is highly suspicious.

Comment: i looking function return result

Comment: Please run the `find` command I posted. What's the output? If that doesn't work you are not doing what you think you are doing.

Comment: its give output with file path i just need result value